# Why many posts here on meta still have links in the old format http://meta.math.stackexchange.com?

Tags: bug, meta, hyperlinks, https

Long time ago, the URL for this meta used to be `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com` - but it later changed to `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/`.
In 2017 it was announced that http-links will be converted to https: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058)
The [current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/292058/13) of that post says, among other things, this: "<kbd>done</kbd> **(Child metas)** Move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`."

Based on that I thought that the URLs in posts and comments linking to meta have been converted to the new format.
And it seems that many replacements of this type were indeed done, as you can see from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1070272/posts-which-contained-the-text-in-some-revision-and-it-was-later-removed-includi?word=http://meta.math.stackexchange.com) or [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1610177/edits-by-the-given-user-between-two-dates?userid=-1&Date1=2017-01-01&Date2=2019-01-01) or [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1038510/edits-by-a-given-user-with-edit-summary-containing-given-word?num=5000&keyword=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.math.stackexchange.com&id=-1).
Here are links to some random examples found from those queries:
[1176](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1176/revisions),
[3624](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3624/revisions),
[11546](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11546/revisions),
[16536](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16536/revisions),
[16594](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16594/revisions),
[21996](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/21996/revisions).

But there are many posts where the link is still in the old format. At the moment, I get [989 posts from search](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Ahttp://meta.math.stackexchange.com%2A%22) and [1011 posts from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1461824/posts-with-arxiv-frontend-links?word=http://meta.math.stackexchange.com). Here are a few random examples: [9687](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9687/8),
[23090](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/23090/4),
[23230](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/23230/8),
[25041](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/25041/3) (this one contains `http://data.stackexchange.com/`, too),
[23128](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/23128/8) (this one also contains `http://math.stackexchange.com`).

Is this an oversight and these links were missed during the conversion to https? Or are the links supposed to be in this way?

If the links should be fixed, can this be done in bulk - rather than manually?

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9750738#9750738

Comment: For benefit of others, the above message links to this post: [How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169)
@uhoh I am aware of that tool - but if the information on [meta.se] is correct, it has already been run on the per-site-metas and still there are plenty of links left. (Which suggest that it is not that reliable - at the same time I understand that catching various formats how links are entered might be tricky.)